# how to insert in two dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

i'am new injava , in this problem i will insert a numbers of strings in a array , but the compiler give me this probleme :
PhoneNumber.java:29: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean
            while(test[i][j])
                         ^
1 error

```
public class PhoneNumber{
   public static void check_number(String[][] numbers, int n)
   {
       int i,j;
       for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           for(j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++)
           {
               if(numbers[i][j] == "4" || numbers[i][j] == "5")
               {
                   System.out.println("Done");

               }
           }   
       }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       String[][] test = new String[100][100];
       Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
       int n,i,j;
       System.out.println("enter the number of numbers");
       n = number.nextInt();
       for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
       {
           System.out.println("enter the number " + i + 1);
                j = 0;
           while(test[i][j])
           {
           test[i][j] = number.nextLine(); 
           j++;
           }
       }
   check_number(test,n);
   }
}
```

Comment: What did you expect that `while` loop to do? Why did you expect that? --- *Hint:* `test[i][j]` is a `String`. The `while` loop expects a `boolean`. Java doesn't support *coercing* a `String` to a `boolean`.

Comment: so how can i insert strings in an array ?

Comment: Are you sure you need a two-dimensional array? It looks like you are trying to build an array of strings, where each string represents a number. That's a 1-D array of strings, not a 2D array of strings. Is that the question?

Comment: yeaah exactly i would to build an array of strings, where each string represents a number

Answer (score -1):

Here's the basic approach for a 1D String array with notes included:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneNumber{
   public static void check_number(String[] numbers, int n)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           System.out.println(numbers[i]);
           //the String class method equals is best for comparison:
           if(numbers[i].equals("4") || numbers[i].equals("5"))
           {
               System.out.println("Done");
           }
       }
   }

public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
       int n;
       System.out.println("enter the number of numbers");
       n = number.nextInt();
       //clean the scanner buffer after input especially with Int -> Line
       number.nextLine();
       //size your array after getting user input
       String[] test = new String[n];
       for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
       {
           //parenthesis needed to get correct output for i + 1
           System.out.println("enter the number " + (i + 1));
           test[i] = number.nextLine(); 
       }
   check_number(test,n);
   }
}
```

Comment: but in this case the code work just when i insert one value; my problem is to insert many phonenumbers , and stock each one in index of the array

Comment: What is test[0][0] supposed to be then?

Comment: test[0][0] supposed to be the first number of a the first numberphone in the array, for example: 
test[0] = "01584752"
test[1] = "54875212"
so test[0][0] = "0"